# Why does Octave give me a syntax error with this basic while loop?

Tags: while-loop, syntax-error, octave, parse-error

I try the while loop with this code on GNU Octave version 4.2.2.:

```
n=0;
while n<5
  disp(n);
  n=n+1;
endwhile
disp('fin')
```

And it shows me this message:

```
parse error:

  syntax error

>>> while
        ^
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. The code is from a Octave tutorial. Please help me.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're just typing those lines into the Command Window individually, instead of storing them in a file?

Comment: @AndrewJanke this shouldn't matter in terms of the while loop though

Comment: If you type this code in the octave terminal by hand, instead of copy/pasting, does the code work? Sometimes there are invisible characters on webpages, that when copy/pasted into terminals result in syntax errors. Similarly, one of the latin-looking letters may have accidentally been swapped for an identically looking letter from a different language / keyboard layout, e.g. a russian "e" in `while` would give you this error.

Comment: hence also this meme: https://pics.me.me/peter-ritchie-peterritchie-follow-mt-replace-a-semicolon-with-27868835.png   :p

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Oh, you're right. Never mind. And it works for me when copy-pasting from this SO question. I suspect you're right about invisible characters from a web page.